# Unable to serve Images from express to Angular6

Tags: node.js, angular, express, file-upload

Node.js code

```
    app.use('/static/images',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images')))

   folder Structure 
    |-root 
    | -images
```

In My Angular6+ I am trying to fetch

```
      this.productService.dataSubject.subscribe((val)=>{
          console.log(val,"we are from Trail Zoom Component",Config.URLS.images+val['product']['imageUrl']) 

          this.productImg = Config.URLS.images+val['product']['imageUrl']
```

In My console i am able to see

```
{product: {…}} "we are from Trail Zoom Component" "http://localhost:3000/static/images/image-1612722550428.jpeg"
```

I cross checked Whether my image is present in my images folder It is Present

i am seeing an Encrypted when opening "http://localhost:3000/static/images/image-1612722550428.jpeg"

[image: The following msg i am seeing when i open my link]

I modified to set Headers For Image (Still facing the issue)

```
app.use('/static/images',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images'),{
    setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
}))

function setCustomCacheControl (res, path) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type','image/jpeg')
    }

My-headers
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setHeader(
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
          'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
        );
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
          return res.sendStatus(200);
        }
        next();
    });
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: What do you mean by this `i am seeing an Encrypted when opening...`?? What do you see in devtools/Network tab?? When you type the url `http://localhost:3000/static/images/image-1612722550428.jpeg` in browser address bar and hit enter what do you get?

Comment: @Molda i have updated my code with the image

Answer (score 0):

I fell bad about myself  Issue resolved after changing the `/static/images` to `/static/images/`

```
app.use('/static/images/',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images'),{
    setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
}))
```